# Maximum weight window air condition without supports?

Tags: windows, air-conditioning

For the average old window what is the maximum weight air condition you should have installed without any support brackets beside screwing in the window frame from the inside?  For example up to 50 pounds ok? 100 pounds risking it?

Comment: Nobody worries about this. Any commercially available unit will work in any window in a structure with anything approaching standard quality construction. If you have some non standard construction you could put braces to the wall or in a first floor window a post to the ground. I once had a 12 kBTU/h window unit in a window in the middle of a long side of a mobile home and I did put a post under the end of the unit.

Comment: Does your unit come with braces supporting the unit to the outside wall?

Comment: @jim I have a 40 pound air condition unit and was looking to replace it with an 80 pound unit but was having second thoughts because of potentially breaking my window and making it more difficult to take out and clean. So to just get another 40 pound unit

Comment: A std window should have no problem with an 80 lb window unit.

Comment: @jim without any supports just with the 2 screws on the side?

Comment: Doesn't the unit come with support brackets to the wall under the unit outside? If not, just install it with the hardware that comes with the unit. Like this https://www.amazon.com/Top-Shelf-TSB-2438-Conditioner-Bracket/dp/B00NKQFSH6/ref=asc_df_B00NKQFSH6/?tag=hyprod-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=167119222542&hvpos=1o1&hvnetw=g&hvrand=12138274876017922430&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9026945&hvtargid=aud-643191255296:pla-274195129643&psc=1

Comment: How much you do would be dependent on the consequences of the a/c unit flipping out onto the ground and the likelihood of this happening with the standard installation. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iNB1KxKL-rs

Comment: You can almost certainly get away with installing the unit with the hardware that comes with it, but it has to be your call.

Comment: IIRC the flange on the a/c fits inside the window so the screws just hold it in place. I like the idea of the bracket brace, but that may not be truly necessary.

Comment: Add a brace no big deal. better dont hurt.

Comment: it's more about stability and resting force than weight. if something is about to fall out except for the window being tightly closed, a heavier one might actually be slightly safer, as it puts more sideways force on the window pane and makes it harder to open. If it's not rocking or sliding, even with the window fully open, 50 vs 100 lbs doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

100 pounds is nothing for a window frame.   Now if you don't have it mounted right you could break, crack or put stress the bottom of the actual window unit.   This isn't a question of weight though, it is a question of how balanced it is and movement.

Is a 100 pound vs 50 pound AC unit more likely to have install issues... probably.

Answer (score 0):

The size is dependent on window opening the weight means nothing even in my old 100 yr wood house but follow the manufacturers instructions for any supports .  Download the manual of one you like and see if it has everything or needs additional hardware.  Follow the manual!!!